# Cypress: When I try to run npx cypress open the window opens and then closes immediately

Tags: automation, cypress

I'm trying to learn cypress, but I haven't been able to get past installation. I follow the documentation, I run `npm init` and then `npm install cypress --save-dev`.

Next I tried running `npx cypress open` and adding to the package.json `"cypress:open" : "cypress open` and then running `npm run cypress:open`. In both cases, the launchpad opens for a few seconds and then closes immediately. I understand that it should create a cypress folder in my directory but it doesn't do anything, just closes. There is no error message or anything similar.

I don't know what to do and I can't find any information regarding this error, please help

[Console when running commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FNfj.png)

Comment: can you try to run `cypress verify` and see what happens? I just created a new folder, initialized npm, added cypress (nothing else there) and works just fine.

Comment: Facing the same issue, got ✔  Verified Cypress! after `cypress verify`

Comment: Could be a Node version problem. Cypress requires Node.js 12 or 14 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by downgrading Cypress to version 10.0.3